# Search in Angular with Elasticsearch

Tags: angular, elasticsearch

so i am very new to Angular and elastic and i need ur help because i am stuck and couldn't find anything online. So i want to make a search bar which sends a GET request to my elasticsearch database and looks for usernames. I am using Angular for my project and like i said i never used both of them before (university project)

So i have my search service which should use the elastic URL with the search for usernames and a getElasticResult methode which sends the GET request with the searched Text/username:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HandleError, HttpErrorHandler} from '../http-error-handler.service';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {User} from '../timeline/user';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SearchService {

  getElastic = 'http://34.65.42.287:9200/users/_doc/_search?q=username:';
  private handleError: HandleError;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('TimelineService');
  }
  /** GET elasticsearch result */
  getElasticResult( text: string ): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.getElastic + text);
  }
}
```

Then i have a component file which creates the search form and a user to safe the user from the GET request. the getUser method reads the text from the form and calls the getElasticResult method to get the  user from elastic and safes it on the newly created user:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {SearchService} from './search.service';
import {User} from '../timeline/user';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-service',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  providers: [SearchService],
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})

export class SearchServiceComponent {
  user: User;
  angForm: FormGroup;


  constructor(private searchservice: SearchService, private  fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createSearchForm();
    console.log('adasd');

  }

  createSearchForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      searchText: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  getUser(text: string): void {
    text = this.angForm.get('searchText').value;
    this.searchservice.getElasticResult(text).subscribe(user => (this.user = user));
  }
}
```

And now to the HTML part of this service. This is where i have no clue what to do to be honest. I tried making a form with the angForm from the component but i do not really now how to send the inputed data to the component and then to show the found user under the searchbar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form [formGroup]="angForm"  class="form-inline my-5 my-lg-0">
  <input id="searchText" name="searchText" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for user" aria-label="Post"
         formControlName="searchText" required>
   <p> {{getUser("elon")}}</p>
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here the searchbar: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the following,

In your component.ts file,

```
getUser() {
 let userName = this.angForm.value.searchText;
 console.log(this.angForm.value, userName);
 this.searchservice.getElasticResult(userName).subscribe(user => (this.user = user))
}
```

Also,

In your component.html file,

Initialize form element, `<form [formGroup]="angForm" (ngSubmit)="getUser()">`

Also, in your component.ts file.

```
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    export class SearchServiceComponent {
     angForm = this.fb.group({
      searchText: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private searchservice: SearchService ) { }

    //Code

    }
```

Comment: thx for the reply, i did that but i don't see anything in the console or under the search bar

Comment: Can you share the Stackblitz link?

Comment: Sorry it is a very big project, and not on Stackblitz

Comment: oh and btw shouldn't the searchservice also be declared in the constructor ?

Comment: Okay i think i got a idea whats wrong haha i saw in my browser that the sent text is not added to the URL as a text but like this "...:9200/users/_doc/_search?q=username:[object%20Object] "

Comment: @SkurSkurrrr, Yes the service needs to be declared in the constructor, I have edited my answer as per your requirement, please mark it, if you find the answer appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks now it passes the correct string but i got a new error:    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://URL...:9200/users/_doc/_search?q=username:elon' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @SkurSkurrrr You need to enable CORS at the API level.

Comment: and how ? ^^ sorry i am new to angular

Comment: ah nvm got that solved but i think i need a request body to show the found user under the search bar?

Comment: @SkurSkurrrr Glad that you were able to solve the issue. However, I am afraid that I can't help you in the issue you are facing currently, as it is out of the scope of the question you had asked in the first place. Kindly raise another question in the forum to get it addressed. Also, kindly accept or up-vote my answer if it helped you resolve your issue in the first place. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for ur help and i did wrote a new question today regarding that

Comment: Glad to know that I was able to assist you in resolving your issue. I will have a look at the question you posted today & try to assist you in resolving the same. Thank you.